# How to get end user's access-key and secret-access-key by using accountId and registered email/username w.r.t "amazon s3" in spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have Spring-boot application I already configured amazon account, I need to get the another account iam user as member to in application

How to get end user's access-key and secret-access-key by using accountId and registered email/username  w.r.t "amazon s3" in spring boot application ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.